# Can I control the color of the first bar in a zingchart waterfall chart?

Tags: zingchart, waterfall

can i control the color of the first bar in a Zingchart waterfall, or must it acquire the positive/negative property? I have tried tweaking the standard waterfall options

Answer (score 0):

Use "styles" attribute in the generic "plot" object or in the "series" item:

Example below styles the 1st and the 3rd node

{
    "type":"waterfall",
    "plot":{
        "styles":[
            {
                "background-color":"#ff0"
            },
            null,
            {
                "background-color":"#f0f"
            }
        ]
    },
    "series":[
        {
            "values":[420,210,-170,-140,"SUM"]
        }
    ]
}